# Slow wireless speed between Ubuntu and OpenWRT

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, openwrt

I have `TpLink WA901 ND` access point with `OpenWRT` installed, which supports up to 450 Mbps.

Unfortunately, from my `Ubuntu` notebook I see only `Bit Rate=52 Mb/s` according to `iwconfig` even within few meters from AP.

Notebook is Dell Inspiron with `Intel Centrino Wireless N 2230`, which supports up to 300 Mbps.

What to check to ensure all capabilities are activated?

**On Ubuntu Notebook**

```
$ iwconfig wlp2s0
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"In The Moon Network"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 60:E3:27:8D:7A:A6   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-29 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:336   Missed beacon:0



$ iw dev wlp2s0 info
Interface wlp2s0
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr 68:17:29:9a:e0:75
    type managed
    wiphy 0
    channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz


$ iw dev wlp2s0 link
Connected to 60:e3:27:8d:7a:a6 (on wlp2s0)
    SSID: In The Moon Network
    freq: 2437
    RX: 39568332 bytes (83031 packets)
    TX: 4846489 bytes (30088 packets)
    signal: -29 dBm
    tx bitrate: 1.0 MBit/s

    bss flags:  CTS-protection short-preamble short-slot-time
    dtim period:    2
    beacon int: 100
```

**On OpenWRT AP**

```
# iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ifindex 6
        wdev 0x2
        addr 60:e3:27:8d:7a:a6
        ssid In The Moon Network
        type AP
        wiphy 0
        channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
        txpower 28.00 dBm

# iwinfo wlan0 info
wlan0     ESSID: "In The Moon Network"
          Access Point: 60:E3:27:8D:7A:A6
          Mode: Master  Channel: 6 (2.437 GHz)
          Tx-Power: 28 dBm  Link Quality: 66/70
          Signal: -44 dBm  Noise: -89 dBm
          Bit Rate: 144.4 MBit/s
          Encryption: WPA2 PSK (CCMP)
          Type: nl80211  HW Mode(s): 802.11bgn
          Hardware: unknown [Generic MAC80211]
          TX power offset: unknown
          Frequency offset: unknown
          Supports VAPs: yes  PHY name: phy0


# iwinfo wlan0 assoclist
68:17:29:9A:E0:75  -39 dBm / -89 dBm (SNR 50)  930 ms ago
        RX: 6.0 MBit/s                                 32886 Pkts.
        TX: 144.4 MBit/s, MCS 15, 20MHz                38245 Pkts.



root@tplink1:/etc/config# cat wireless
config wifi-device  radio0
        option type     mac80211
        option channel  auto
        option hwmode   11g
        option path     'platform/qca956x_wmac'
        option htmode   HT40+
        # REMOVE THIS LINE TO ENABLE WIFI:
        option disabled 0

config wifi-iface
        option device   radio0
        option network  lan
        option mode     ap
        option ssid     'In The Moon Network'
        option encryption psk2
```

Answer (score 1):

This are a lot of little reasons that all add up to wireless networking being slower than the advertised rate. Ars Technica recently did a [really good article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/03/802-eleventy-what-a-deep-dive-into-why-wi-fi-kind-of-sucks/) about why real-life speeds never live up to what was promised, and I'll do my best to summarize it into a few succinct points. I still encourage you to read the article in whole, the author is a lot more knowledgeable and experienced than I.

To start, networked devices can only operate at the highest speed of the slowest device, which in your case is the 300 Mb/s of the laptop's wireless card. But that's the maximum theoretical bandwidth which doesn't include [overhead](https://www.cwnp.com/wi-fi-overhead-part-1-sources-of-overhead/), the things like dropped packets, headers, and random waits to ensure no packet collisions are happening on the channel. Your 300 Mb/s wifi card is really two [MIMO streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO) of 150 Mb/s, which have a real throughput of [~42 Mb/s](http://80211notes.blogspot.com/2014/03/phy-rate-and-udp-throughput.html) each due to the overhead on the channel. Two channels of 42 is 84 Mb/s, but wifi is also [half duplex](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12600696/wireless-half-duplex-or-full-duplex), which means that you can not transmit or receive at the same time. This is because the whole channel is a single [collision domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_domain) meaning that to prevent packet loss only a single device can communicate on the channel at a given time, even devices that aren't on your network but are on the same channel must obey this.

So then we are reduced to ~42 Mb/s real throughput. ~42 Mb/s doesn't match any standard for throughput, so I'm guessing your operating system probably rounds it to the nearest standard it knows (don't quote me on that part though), which is how you end up with 52 Mb/s on a 300 Mb/s interface.

Comment: What I have is that connection is REPORTED as 52 Mb/s. I would agree if it was REPORTED 300 or 150 Mb/s but actual throughput was lower. Also, the actual my problem is that I am unable to see HD 720p movies well and do remote desktop. When this notebook was under Windows, I was able to do this. Unfortunately, I can't check what reportings there were under Windows. This is why I think that the problem is not with what you described, but some logical misconfig.

Comment: You should have included that information in the original question because it is pertinent to the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Bitrate in iwconfig is (approximately) the base channel rate, not what you are experiencing.  Higher speeds are achieved by using more channels at once, to put it way too simply.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009) has plenty of detail on it.

Your driver may support different "modulations", e.g. you can perhaps select N only and get better throughput.

`iwlist modulation`  should show what's available.

The reported speed from iwconfig is the radio channel base rate -- what do you actually see with, say, `iperf` or similar?

Comment: I get ``wlan17    unknown modulation information.``